# How to use the recursion theorem in proofs

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have tried using the  recursion theorem in proofs and found out that I am not sure how to do that. for example, Take the claim:

> Given a linearly ordered set $A$, $A$ is well ordered if and only if $A$ does not contain an infinite decreasing sequence.

I know how to prove it, but, as an exercise I am trying to prove it using the  recursion theorem, and, it seems that I don't know where to start.

By  recursion theorem I meant:

For every class function $F\colon V \rightarrow V$, there is a unique $g$, with domain $\delta$, such that $(\forall \alpha < \delta) (g(\alpha)=F((g(\beta)));\beta<\alpha))$
(where $\alpha,\beta,\delta$ are ordinals)

Thank you!
Shir

Comment: Exactly what do you mean with the "recurrence theorem"? Including its statement would be the safest bet.

Comment: I have added above the theorem I meant.  Thanks, Shir

Comment: That's the *recursion theorem*. Thanks for editing, I expect the question to be reopened soon.

Comment: How $\beta$ fits into the quantification is very unclear to me.

Comment: I am more than sure that this was discussed before.